Pass data to websocket on POST request | FastAPI
I have an application that allows multiple bots to connect to it via /ws/{bot_id} endpoint. I'm storing all the connections inside websockets dict. When someone makes a POST request I want to pass some data to the websocket connection, but it's not letting me because the connection is already closed somehow:
RuntimeError: Unexpected ASGI message 'websocket.send', after sending 'websocket.close' or response already completed
import asyncio
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket

app = FastAPI()
websockets: dict[int, WebSocket] = {}


@app.websocket("/ws/{bot_id}")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, bot_id: int):
    websockets[bot_id] = websocket
    await websocket.accept()


@app.post("/bot/{bot_id}/start_lobby")
async def start_lobby(bot_id: int):
    websocket = websockets.get(bot_id)
    await websocket.send_text("START")


@app.post("/bot/{bot_id}/quit_lobby")
async def destroy_lobby(bot_id: int):
    websocket = websockets.get(bot_id)
    await websocket.send_text("DELETE")

Here's the minimal code on a bot client that listens to everything (stdout is always empty):
def websocket_connection():
    with connect("ws://localhost:8000/ws/1") as websocket:
        while True:
            message = websocket.recv()
            if message == "START":
                start_lobby()
            elif message == "DELETE":
                destroy_lobby()
            websocket.send("BOT 1: RECEIVED")
            print(f"Received: {message}")


In addition to the link provided above, please have a look at this answer, as well as this answer and this answer. You might find this helpful as well.

You need to keep open connection with client.
Example to fix ws handler
@app.websocket("/ws/{bot_id}")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, bot_id: int):
    websockets[bot_id] = websocket
    await websocket.accept()
    while True:
        data = await websocket.receive()
        print(data)

Logs:
Server
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49200 - "POST /bot/1/start_lobby HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
{'type': 'websocket.receive', 'text': 'BOT 1: RECEIVED'}

Client
starting lobby
Received: START

